# Array Decays to Pointer in Lambda

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, lambda

```
template<std::size_t size>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(int const (&)[size])
{
    return size;
}

int main()
{
    auto const lambda = [](int const arr[]) -> void
    {
        std::cout << "The length of the array is: " << arraySize(arr) << std::endl;
    };

    lambda({1, 2, 3});

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives the following output:

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:23:69: error: no matching function for call to 'arraySize(const int*&)'
         std::cout << "The length of the array is: " << arraySize(arr) << std::endl;
                                                                     ^
main.cpp:12:23: note: candidate: template<long long unsigned int size> constexpr std::size_t arraySize(const int (&)[size])
 constexpr std::size_t arraySize(int const (&)[size])
                       ^
main.cpp:12:23: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:23:69: note:   mismatched types 'const int [size]' and 'const int*'
         std::cout << "The length of the array is: " << arraySize(arr) << std::endl;
                                                                     ^
```

I want to stop `int const arr[]` from decaying into a pointer.  If I use a reference, it requires a template to get the size, just like arraySize.  Templates don't work with lambdas.  Is this possible, or do I have to use a function instead, or pass the length as a parameter?

Comment: One solution would be to change your lambda to take a `std::initializer_list` as a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not decay. Decay is when an *expression* of array type is converted to a pointer.

The things in a function parameter list are not expressions; they are declarators. In this situation, an array declarator is *adjusted* to be a pointer declarator, e.g.:

```
void f(int const arr[]);
```

is equivalent to:

```
void f(int const *arr);
```

Lambdas are no exception to this; the lambda function behaves like a member function of a custom class holding the captured variables.

---

You may pass an array by reference, to avoid this adjustment:

```
auto const lambda = [](int const (&arr)[size]) -> void
```

Using C++14 generic lambdas, this option also receives the array by reference:

```
auto const lambda = [](auto& arr) -> void
```

In this latter case, the `const` is also deduced thanks to reference collapsing.

As far as I know, it's not possible to have the lambda *only* accept an array but still deduce the array size.

Comment: I was looking at polymorphic C++14 lambdas, but I guess I didn't get far enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Not possible?  [This is C++](http://zombo.com/).  (Change `->void` to `->std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arr)>>{}>`).  Worth it?  Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly how many different kinds of array sizes you want this to work with, you might want different solutions.

If the array sizes you need it to work with are known at compile time, one thing I would consider is to use std::array, that is, make a template function which generates an appropriate lambda function which takes `std::array` of a particular size. And use that lambda function with arrays of that size.

If the sizes of the possible arrays aren't known at compile time, then I guess I would recommend to pass a `std::vector` to the lambda instead.